# Can I pass an anonymous object into a method that expects a reference parameter of type object?

Tags: c#, .net, anonymous-types, ref

I'd like to know why the first call to `Bar(ref object)` doesn't work and the second one does. Seems silly considering I'm passing in a type `object` either way, **and** passing in an anonymous type to `Foo(object)` works fine. Why would `ref`, something that has to do with memory location influence the calls to `Bar()`?

Consider the following snippet:

```
static void Foo(object obj)
{ }

static void Bar(ref object obj)
{ }

static void Main()
{
    // Compiles
    var a = new { };
    Foo(a);

    // Does not compile
    var b = new { };
    Bar(ref b);

    // Compiles
    object c = new { };
    Bar(ref c);
}
```

I see in the answers below suggestions on how to make the code compile, but that's not what I'm after. I'd like to know specifically why making it a `ref` parameter prevents compilation when passing in an anonymous type to `Foo()` worked fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main reason is a little hidden: this happens because your passed in argument has to be the *exact* same type as the type defined in the parameter.

This is (ambiguously?) stated in the specification section $10.6.1.2:

> When a formal parameter is a reference parameter, the corresponding argument in a method invocation must
>   consist of the keyword ref **followed by a variable-reference** (§5.3.3) **of the same type as the formal parameter**.

For this very same reason, passing a subclass to a method that uses a reference parameter doesn't work. This is described in Jeff Mercado's answer.

In your first example you don't use `ref` so polymorphism works (an anonymous type is a subtype of `object`) and in the last example you declare it as `object` which means you use the exact same type as the reference parameter.

Answer (score 5):

Why should it? The variable `b` is not declared as an `object` as is expected by the method.

Consider this example:

```
string s;
GetValue(ref s); // no...

void GetValue(ref object x)
{
    x = 123;
}
```

Comment: thanks. But passing in an anonymous to `Foo(object)` was not an issue. Why when making the parameter a `ref` does it prevent compilation?

Comment: I could site the spec but the example should make it perfectly clear why it _should_ fail.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is equally good but I appreciate the spec citation below. Thanks anyway, I upvoted this :)

Answer (score 0):

by not allowing the function with ref along with parameter type, the compiler is actually preventing to have compromise with type safety. The same happens in the following scenario as well

```
    private static void MyMethod(out object MyPara)
    {
        MyPara = new String('x', 10);
    }

    MyClass obj = new MyClass();
    MyMethod(out obj); //compile time error
```

Compiler is actually keeping the memory location of obj safe by not allowing this scenario to compile. If this would have been allowed security of the application can be easily compromised

Answer (score -1):

Type inference is smart, but it is unable to read your mind. So just declaring `var b = new { };` is simply not enough information to make the compiler understand, that you want something, that can be ref-passed as an Object.

```
var b = new Object ();
Bar (ref b);
```

will work ofcourse.

Comment: This is actually incorrect answer - as other answers point out the same error will happen for any type mismatch - there is no type inference involved here.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - the moment you use `var`, the moment type inference comes into play - and this **creates** the type mismatch. And the moment you give enough information to `var`, that it gets the correct type, the type mismatch (and the resulting compile time error) will disappear.

Comment: `var` uses the exact right type behind the scenes, nothing is inferred incorrectly. By defining the anonymous type as an `object` you simply upcast it to a more general specification which does fit the method's definition. Creating it as an object instead doesn't answer the question because now you don't use an anonymous type.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - your comment is contratictionary! If `var`already uses the fitting type, how can defining it as an object make it fitting?

Comment: I see what you mean... Indeed there is type inference for var (it looks like OP knows that it will set particular type and not asking about that line). Obviously code *after* declaration have no impact on declaration too - so while technically there is inferrence, from my point of view it is not related to the line of code the question is about.

Comment: @EugenRieck: it's the whole "work towards an interface, not an implementation" principle. In the Animal - Dog hierarchy this equals to creating a new object of type `Dog` but assigning it to a variable of type `Animal`. Even though it is a dog, you will only be able to use it as an animal. Which, in turn, allows it to be passed to something that only accepts references of type animal. `var` is substituted for the exact type that is being instantiated. `object` is needed to upcast this reference to the kind of reference that the method expects.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel ... which is exactly what I said: The type inference choses a type, that does not fit the method (as the mthod call comes later). Give it enough information, and it will chose a different type, which does fit the method.

Comment: @EugenRieck: the way you phrase it is what causes the issue here. You say "give it enough information" and propose to create an instance of type `object`, that's not correct at all. It already has exactly enough information, you're just passing in the wrong type. Creating an anonymous type here is exactly the same as creating a new `HttpClient()`: both will fail if you use `var` because it substitutes for exactly that type. Upcast them to `object` and it will work. This is not a lack of information, it's just passing in wrong information. Using `new object()` is not a solution for this reason.

Comment: @EugenRieck probably you should have made sample `var b = (Object( new {});` than to fit "Give it enough information, and it will chose a different type, which does fit the method."

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - we will have to agree to disagree on that: I read "give it enough information" as "tell it what type you want (namely something that can be ref-passed as object)", and I stand to that. I suspect we differ in approach - yours is the compiler's POV, mine is the developers POV.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - this would be a syntax error, so I'd rather not.

Comment: @EugenRieck: I do indeed take the language-lawyer perspective here but regardless of how we look at the phrasing: the solution isn't appropriate. Either you assign it to a variable of type `object` or you cast it to `object` but you can't create an instance of `object` because then you don't use the anonymous type anymore, which was the point of the question.

Comment: Missed brace - I meant cast - `var b = (Object)( new {});` to force `Object` as type.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - Let's just agree to disagree.